# can not Install ML.EXE

Tags: assembly

I obtained Visual studio express 2005 and installed it.
I was no able to register it as the registration site does not exist eny more.
I downloaded MASMsetup.EXE from MS official download center.

I ran it, when it de compresses before finishing, or starting the next step it disapers.

What am I doing wrong?

OK, its 9 years old. My target is users with XP windows. I don't want a sophisticated IDE, just a simple one to code and debug assembly with API calls for mass storage access. 
What free ware can I use for MASM32.

Comment: It probably finished just fine, it takes milliseconds, it is very small.  Do avoid wasting your time on 9 year old software, much has changed since then.

Comment: http://www.masm32.com/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2005 includes ML.EXE, version 8.00.x , which is the actual name for MASM since version 6.11 and the days of MSDOS. Usually if there's a MASM.EXE, it's for backwards compatibility with versions 5.x and older.

When creating a project, just add the .asm file as existing item to a project and you should get prompted to create a custom build step. If you want to define your own, right click on the  source file .asm name to get into custom properties, go into configuration manager and create custom build step. For debug build "command line" should be:

ml /Zi /c /Fo$(outdir)\example.obj example.asm

For release build it should be:

ml /c /Fo$(outdir)\example.obj example.asm

For debug or release build "outputs" should be:

$(outdir)\example.obj

To determine how to create the equivalent of main() or how to call the c library functions, create a .C file based project, and enable assembly output with the C / C++ options, then use the generated assembly code as a guide.